# Html5 path align issue arabic version

Tags: html, css, svg

i need to make menu tab like this

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tsouG

but i need that curved part on the left not right  i try to edit in path code but its not work can any one help please?

```
 <div class="banner">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="cssmenu">
                    <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">

  <a href="" class="videos">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>
    <span></span>
  </a>

  <a href="../ArabicNewLogin.aspx" class="almanac">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>الرئيسيه</span>
  </a>
  <a href="../ArabicTal2aLogin.aspx" class="snippets">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>عميل طلقه</span>
  </a>
  <a href="../ArabicFAQs.html" class="forums">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>التعليمات</span>
  </a>



</nav>
         </div>
                <div class="lang">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn1" href="../NewLogin.aspx">انجليزى</a> <a class="btn btn-primary bt"
                        href="../ArabicNewLogin.aspx">عربى</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <svg class="hide">

  <defs>
  <path id="shape-tab" d="M100,25C79.568,25,84.815,0,59.692,0H11.149C5.027,0,0,4.634,0,10.385V25"></path>


  </defs>

</svg>
```

This is my effort on it till now

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rIAlc

Comment: what are your efforts till now?

Comment: I edit my Effort so far

Comment: that's the answer i finish it thanks a lot

    </nav>
     <svg class="hide">
    
      <defs>
      <path id="shape-tab" d="M0,25C20.432,25,15.185,0,40.308,0h48.543C94.973,0,100,4.634,100,10.385V25"></path>
    
    
      </defs>
    
    </svg>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

I also improved your original version. Now it's all relative, so you only have to give the first coordinates (`M116.486,29.036`) and the rest will be drawn relative to that point:

- Original: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jouHh**
- Mirror: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGcfb**

---

### **UPDATE**

Oh, I see now I should have worked with the code in your question, not the codepen 
example. It would have been handy to have had your own code in a codepen from the 
start, this pretty much renders my first solution useless.

But here it is again.
I've improved your original path first again, so it's easier to mirror:

**Original** (**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwzfB**):

```
<path id="shape-tab" d="M100,25 
                        c-20.432,0 -15.185,-25 -40.308,-25 
                        h-48.543 
                        c-6.122,0 -11.149,4.634 -11.149,10.385 
                        v25
                        z" />
```

**Mirror** (**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGJxw**):

```
<path id="shape-tab" d="M0,25 
                     c20.432,0 15.185,-25 40.308,-25 
                     h48.543 
                     c6.122,0 11.149,4.634 11.149,10.385 
                     v25
                     z" />
```

Comment: i add your code in my own edition and its not work do you know why?